# Using bluetooth to add my own files or rewrite files to a bluetooth connected cnc

Tags: api, bluetooth, sdk, cnc

I have a bluetooth enabled CNC(key cutter) that I control it from my phone via an app(ios but an equivalent is available for android). I need to be able to gain access to the machine directly with bluetooth or usb(already tried on pc) so I can try to find the correct memory offsets and values so I can change precoded names, values, for already existing "cutting profiles"(Not sure if these files are in the CNC or the app).

Trying to reverse engineer the app seems like a waste of time until I can at LEAST discern which files to expect are kept on the cnc, and which files are kept within the app.

I have experience with memory editors such as cheat engine, a little C / C++.

I have tried searching for solutions based in Bluetooth, but that is only getting be basic file transfer explanations. The app gives no direct access to files of any kind.

ANY help pointing me in the right direction for where to start with this problem, or reference material you think would be relevant would be helpful.